# Whats the best way of saving a document with revisions in a key value store?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, key-value, nosql

I'm new to Key-Value Stores and I need your recommendation. We're working on a system that manages documents and their revisions. A bit like a wiki does. We're thinking about saving this data in a key value store.

Please don't give me a recommendation that is the database you prefer because we want to hack it so we can use many different key value databases. We're using node.js so we can easily work with json.

My Question is: What should the structure of the database look like? We have meta data for each document(timestamp, lasttext, id, latestrevision) and we have data for each revision (the change, the author, timestamp, etc...). So, which key/value structure you recommend?

thx

Comment: I'm thinking aloud: why don't you build a small wrapper around GIT or SVN and let those do the versioning? The user doesn't have know about those things...

Comment: cause we need to access every changeset, to do stuff like a timeslider

Comment: Which actually can be accessed very easily with GIT, like looking up save point with `git log` or `svn log` and then checkout the needed document. You could even cache those results to improve performance. I'm just saying: don't reinvent wheels ;)

Comment: What I forgot to say: Its really realtime. Means there will be several revisions per second. Means again, to save this with git, you have to spawn many git processes

Comment: Please select the best answer!

Answer (score 5):

Cribbed from the MongoDB [groups](http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/660a26ed47365ff7#). It is somewhat specific to MongoDB, however, it is pretty generic.

Most of these history implementations break down to two common strategies.

### Strategy 1: embed history

In theory, you can embed the history of a document inside of the document itself. This can even be done atomically.

```
> db.docs.save( { _id : 1, text : "Original Text" } ) 
> var doc = db.docs.findOne() 
> db.docs.update( {_id: doc._id}, { $set : { text : 'New Text' }, $push : { hist : doc.text } } ) 
> db.docs.find() 
{ "_id" : 1, "hist" : [ "Original Text" ], "text" : "New Text" }
```

### Strategy 2: write history to separate collection

```
> db.docs.save( { _id : 1, text : "Original Text" } ) 
> var doc = db.docs.findOne() 
> db.docs_hist.insert ( { orig_id : doc._id, ts : Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000), data : doc } ) 
> db.docs.update( {_id:doc._id}, { $set : { text : 'New Text' }  } )
```

Here you'll see that I do two writes. One to the master collection and 
one to the history collection. 
To get fast history lookup, just grab the original ID:

```
> db.docs_hist.ensureIndex( { orig_id : 1, ts : 1 }) 
> db.docs_hist.find( { orig_id : 1 } ).sort( { ts : -1 } )
```

---

- Both strategies can be enhanced by only displaying diffs
- You could hybridize by adding a link from `history collection` to `original collection`

> Whats the best way of saving a document with revisions in a key value store?

It's hard to say there is a "best way". There are obviously some trade-offs being made here.

**Embedding:**

- atomic changes on a single doc
- can result in large documents, may break the reasonable size limits
- probably have to enhance code to avoid returning full hist when not necessary

**Separate collection:**

- easier to write queries
- not atomic, needs two operations (*do you have transactions?*)
- more storage space (*extra indexes on original docs*)

Answer (score 1):

I'd keep a hierarchy of the real data under each document with the revision data attached, for instance:

```
{ 
  [
    {
      "timestamp" : "2011040711350621",
      "data" : { ... the real data here .... }
    },
    {
      "timestamp" : "2011040711350716",
      "data" : { ... the real data here .... }
    }
  ]
}
```

Then use the push operation to add new versions and periodically remove the old versions.  You can use the last (or first) filter to only get the latest copy at any given time.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are multiple approaches and this question is old but I'll give my two cents as I was working on this earlier this year. I have been using MongoDB.

In my case, I had a User account that then had Profiles on different social networks. We wanted to track changes to social network profiles and wanted revisions of them so we created two structures to test out. Both methods had a User object that pointed to foreign objects. We did not want to embed objects from the get-go.

A User looked something like:

```
User {
  "tags"              : [Tags]
  "notes"             : "Notes"
  "facebook_profile"  : <combo_foreign_key>
  "linkedin_profile"  : <same as above>
}
```

and then, for the combo_foreign_key we used this pattern (Using Ruby interpolation syntax for simplicity)

```
combo_foreign_key = "#{User.key}__#{new_profile.last_updated_at}"

facebook_profiles {
  combo_foreign_key: facebook_profile
  ... and you keep adding your foreign objects in this pattern
}
```

This gave us O(1) lookup of the latest FacebookProfile of a User but required us to keep the latest FK stored in the User object. If we wanted all of the FacebookProfiles we would then ask for all keys in the facebook_profiles collection with the prefix of "#{User.key}__" and this was O(N)...

The second strategy we tried was storing an array of those FacebookProfile keys on the User object so the structure of the User object changed from

```
  "facebook_profile"  : <combo_foreign_key>
```

to

```
  "facebook_profile"  : [<combo_foreign_key>]
```

Here we'd just append on the new combo_key when we added a new profile variation. Then we'd just do a quick sort of the "facebook_profile" attribute and index on the largest one to get our latest profile copy. This method had to sort M strings and then index the FacebookProfile based on the largest item in that sorted list. A little slower for grabbing the latest copy but it gave us the advantage knowing every version of a Users FacebookProfile in one swoop and we did not have to worry about ensuring that foreign_key was really the latest profile object.

At first our revision counts were pretty small and they both worked pretty well. I think I prefer the first one over the second now.

Would love input from others on ways they went about solving this issue. The GIT idea suggested in another answer actually sounds really neat to me and for our use case would work quite well... Cool.